# Need help displaying image uploaded from UIImagePicker onto ImageView with a CollectionView cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Building an app in Xcode and I'm trying to get my UIImageView's image to change to the image selected from the ImagePicker. Im dealing with an ImageView belonging to a reusable cell in my UICollectionView. All the code works except changing the actual image.

I've tried to run the code through the corresponding view controller, I've tried to add the code to the UIColletionViewCell's class, and I tried to reload the data of the collection view.

```swift
//image picker code
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UIImageView) {
        let uploadPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        uploadPicker.delegate = self
        present(uploadPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
            print("The photo is \(originalImage)")
        }
        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            let cell = UploadImageCell()
            cell.imageContainer.image = selectedImage
            print("Thumbs Up!!")
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        dismissView()
    }

// CollectionView Code:

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imageCellId, for: indexPath) as! UploadImageCell
            let imageOption = ImageOption(rawValue: indexPath.row)
            cell.imageContainer.image = imageOption?.icon()
            cell.imageContainer.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cell.uploadPhoto(_:))))
            return cell
        }
        /* other sections use different cells*/
}


//CollectionViewCell Code:

class UploadImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // Mark: -  Properties

    let imageContainer: UIImageView = {
        let imageContainer = UIImageView()
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        imageContainer.backgroundColor = .blue
        imageContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageContainer
    }()

    let uploadButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Upload Image", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: button.frame.width, height: 2)
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(imageContainer)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
                imageContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
        ])

        addSubview(uploadButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            uploadButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            uploadButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            uploadButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            uploadButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

expect output of imageContainer.image to be value of "selectedImage"

Answer (score 0):

You need load cell from collectionView instead create new cell

```
var selectedCell: UploadImageCell?
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UIImageView) {
        let uploadPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        uploadPicker.delegate = self
        // Get selected cell
        for cell  in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let uploadCell = cell as? UploadImageCell {
                if uploadCell.imageContainer == sender {
                     selectedCell = uploadCell
                }
            }
        }

        present(uploadPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
            print("The photo is \(originalImage)")
        }
        // Use selectedcell
        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker, let cell = selectedCell {
            cell.imageContainer.image = selectedImage
            print("Thumbs Up!!")
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        dismissView()
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and the Image Container image still doesn't change. I don't think the if let for selectedImage is executed anymore.

Comment: @Sodynamite Please debug your code to find problem. Or provide sample source, I will help you find

Comment: Currently debugging to see what code isn't behaving properly and I believe its the uploadPhoto code. I placed a print statement with the 
```swift
if let uploadCell = cell as? UploadImageCell {
                if uploadCell.imageContainer == sender {
/* Problem code... image.container !== sender */
                    selectedCell = uploadCell
                    print("This code works, \(String(describing: selectedCell))")
                }
            }
```

Comment: also my selector function was not defined inside the CollectionViewCell. It was defined in the ViewController that I configured the UICollectionView on.